# Улучшение сложности Венгерского алгоритма

Tags: оптимизация, графы, комбинаторика, дискретная-математика

В данный момент пишу реализацию Венгерского алгоритма для решения задачи о назначениях. На каждой итерации алгоритма максимальное паросочетание ищется заново (а не путем преобразования предыдущего). Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно оптимизировать этот момент и прийти к асимптотической сложности O(n^4) вместо O(n^5).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

typedef struct Edge {
    int weight;
    int direction; // -1 - left, 0 - both, 1 - right
};

int N=0;

int* matchingLeft; 
int* matchingRight;
bool* visitedKuhn; 
bool* visitedLeft;
bool* visitedRight;
Edge** matrix; 

void prepareForMaximum()
{
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        int maxElem=0;
        for(int j=0; j<N; j++)
        {
            if(matrix[i][j].weight>maxElem) maxElem=matrix[i][j].weight;
        }
        for(int j=0; j<N; j++)
        {
            matrix[i][j].weight=abs(matrix[i][j].weight-maxElem);
        }
    }
}

bool dfs_kuhn(int v)
{
  if(visitedKuhn[v]) return false;  visitedKuhn[v]=true;
  for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
    if(matrix[v][i].weight==0 && (matchingRight[i]==-1 || dfs_kuhn(matchingRight[i])))
    {
      matchingLeft[v]=i;
      matchingRight[i]=v;
      return true;
    }
  return false;
}

void dfs_konig(int v, bool isLeft)
{
  if(isLeft && visitedLeft[v]) return; 
  if(!isLeft && visitedRight[v]) return; 
  if(isLeft) visitedLeft[v]=true;
  else visitedRight[v]=true;
  for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
  {
    if(matrix[v][i].weight==0 && isLeft && matrix[v][i].direction != -1)
    dfs_konig(i, !isLeft);
    if(matrix[i][v].weight==0 && !isLeft && matrix[i][v].direction != 1)
    dfs_konig(i, !isLeft);
  }
}


int main()
{
    cin >> N;
    int counter=0;
    matrix=new Edge*[N];
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        matrix[i]=new  Edge[N];
        for(int j=0; j<N; j++)
        {
            cin >> matrix[i][j].weight;
            matrix[i][j].direction = 0;
        }
    } 
    int** data = new int*[N]; 
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        data[i]=new  int[N];
        for(int j=0; j<N; j++)
        {
            data[i][j] = matrix[i][j].weight;
        }
    }
    prepareForMaximum();
    matchingLeft = new int[N];
    matchingRight = new int[N];
    visitedKuhn = new bool[N];
    visitedLeft = new bool[N];
    visitedRight = new bool[N];
    while(true)
    {
        counter=0;
        std::fill( matchingLeft, matchingLeft+N, -1 );
        std::fill( matchingRight, matchingRight+N, -1 );
        for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
        {
            std::fill( visitedKuhn, visitedKuhn+N, false );
            if(dfs_kuhn(i)) counter++;
        }
        if(counter==N) { break; }
        else
        {
            for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
            {
                for(int j=0; j<N; j++)
                {
                    matrix[i][j].direction=1;
                }
            }
            for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
            {
                if(matchingLeft[i]!=-1) {
                    matrix[i][matchingLeft[i]].direction=-1;
                }
            }

            std::fill( visitedLeft, visitedLeft+N, false );
            std::fill( visitedRight, visitedRight+N, false);
            for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
            {
                if(matchingLeft[i]==-1) dfs_konig(i, true);
            }
            int min_edge=INT32_MAX;
            for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
            {
                for(int j=0; j<N; j++)
                {
                    if(visitedLeft[i] && !visitedRight[j] && matrix[i][j].weight<min_edge) {
                        min_edge=matrix[i][j].weight;
                    }
                }
            }
            for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
            {
                for(int j=0; j<N; j++)
                {
                    if(visitedLeft[i] && !visitedRight[j]) {
                    matrix[i][j].weight=matrix[i][j].weight-min_edge;
                    }
                    else if(!visitedLeft[i] && visitedRight[j]) {
                    matrix[i][j].weight=matrix[i][j].weight+min_edge;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    int profit=0; // общая выгода
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
             for(int j=0; j<N; j++)
            {
                    if(matchingLeft[i]==j)  profit+=data[i][j];         
} // узнаем веса ребер из паросочетания в исходной матрице
    }
    cout << profit;
    delete matchingLeft;
    delete matchingRight;
    delete visitedKuhn;
    delete visitedLeft;
    delete visitedRight;
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        delete matrix[i];
        delete data[i];
    }
    delete matrix;
    delete data;
    return 0;
}
```